# Let $T_n,...,T_1:V \to V$ be surjective linear operators with finite kernels. Then $\text{ker}(T_n...T_1)=\text{ker}(T_n)+...+\text{ker}(T_1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over $F$.  Let $T_n,...,T_1:V \to V$ be surjective linear operators with finite dimensional kernels.  Is it true that $\text{ker}(T_n...T_1)=\text{ker}(T_n)+...+\text{ker}(T_1)$?

If so can anyone give hint as to proof.

Comment: No, consider the vector space of finitely supported sequences with values in $F$, and consider $T_1 = T_2$ the left-shift operator $T_1(f_1, f_2, f_3, \cdots) = (f_2, f_3, \cdots)$.

Comment: @Joppy Sorry I meant $T_n,..,T_1$ be linear.  Does that make any difference?

Comment: @helios321 The left shift operator **is** linear.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ok one last side question, does it matter if V is finite dimensional?

Comment: If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then surjective operators are also bijective.